# Variation of Bin Packing/Knapsack problem

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

## Statement of Problem

We are given four different collections of objects (apples, bananas, oranges and melons), and must store them in N bins. Bins can only store a single type of object, but the amount of each which can be stored may vary; for a given bin n, it may store 3 apples, 2 bananas, 2 oranges, and no melons. A different bin m may store 2 apples, 2 bananas, 2 oranges, and 2 melons.

Given some collection of objects, and some collection of bins, is it possible to allocate bins to store some type of object, such that all of the items may be stored?

### Example - Successfully storing all objects

Objects: 4 apples, 3 bananas, 2 oranges, no melons.
Bins:

- Bin 1; Space for 2 of any kind.
- Bin 2; 3 Apples, 2 Bananas, 2 Oranges, 2 Melons
- Bin 3; Space for 3 of any kind.
- Bin 4; 1 orange.
- Bin 5; 1 orange.

In this case, the objects may be stored by the following distribution: store apples in bins 1 and 2, store bananas in bin 3, store oranges in bins 4 and 5.

### Current work

In my current implementation, I employ a brute force method.

(This problem is the problem of "how many farm animals may be stored in a cave," from the board game Caverna)

Comment: How fast algorithm are you looking for?

Comment: I have never heard of the caverna game! I thought of a question recently https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4613909/number-of-ways-customers-can-leave-a-grocery-store - maybe it is related!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have $n$ bins and fruits $f_1,\ldots,f_m$. Let the upper bound on the number of fruits of type $f_k$ in bin $s$ be $b(f_k,s)$. A rephrase of the problem is as follows:

Given any term in the product below, can you find which terms of the product multiply to form the term in the product?

$$\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\left(f_i^{b(f_1,i)}+f_2^{b(f_2,i)}+\ldots+f_m^{b(f_m,i)}\right)$$

The reason why this works is that each multiplicand in the product represents a bucket, and we pick one fruit in each bucket.

You can use generating functionology from here.

Comment: great answer! if you had time, could you please write a small example that shows how someone would use this formula to make calculations? thank you so much!