# Number of Ways Customers can Leave a Grocery Store?

Tags: combinatorics

While shopping at a grocery store today, I thought of the following math problem:

- Suppose a grocery store has 10 apples, 13 pears, 8 oranges and 2 bananas
- Suppose there are 5 customers
- The first customer enters the store and makes a purchase - this customer can buy everything the store has, buy nothing, or buy some combination of items
- The second customer then enters the store, and makes a purchase based on the remaining items that the first customer did not buy (note: the second customer is not forced to buy something and can leave empty-handed)
- The third customer then enters the store, and makes a purchase based on the remaining items that the first and second customer did not buy
- Repeat this logic until the last customer

Question:

- **At the end of the day - how many different combinations can exist that describe the remaining items in the store?**
- E.g. 1st Combination : 10 apples, 13 pears, 8 oranges and 2 bananas
- E.g. 2nd Combination: 10 apples, 13 pears, 8 oranges and 1 bananas
- E.g. N-th Combination : 0 apples, 0 pears, 0 oranges and 0 bananas
- **How many different baskets between these 5 customers could have been formed?**

Here are the two ideas I had:

- There are 10 + 13 + 8 + 2 = 33 items in the store . This means that the first customer can fill their basket 2^33 number of ways (i.e. power set)
- Originally, I had thought that 10 * 12 * 8 * 2 = 1920 number of ways that could describe the number of items left in the store (but I am not sure if this number is relevant)

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that each of the customers bought nothing.

It is also possible that each type of fruit was cleaned out.

For any given type of fruit, if there are $n$ pieces to begin with, then there are the following $(n+1)$ possibilities for how many pieces of fruit remain:

$$\{0,1,2,\cdots,n\}.$$

So, the desired computation of the number of combinations that remain in the store is

$$(10 + 1) \times (13 + 1) \times (8+1) \times (2+1).$$

---

For Stars and Bars theory, see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

---

For each piece of fruit, to determine the number of different combinations of who bought that fruit, you want the number of solutions to

- $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + c = n$
- $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_5, c \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

The idea is that $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_5$ can sum to any number in the set $\{0,1,\cdots,n\}.$  Hence the use of the $c$ variable.

So, for a given piece of fruit, there are

$$\binom{n+5}{5} ~~\text{combinations}.$$

So, the total number of combinations of the various
customer purchases is

$$\binom{15}{5} \times \binom{18}{5} \times \binom{13}{5} \times \binom{7}{5}.$$

Comment: @ user2661923 : thank you for your answer!  can you please explain where 15, 18, 13, 7 come from?

Comment: @stats_noob $(10 + 5), (13 + 5), (8 + 5), (2 + 5).$

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start by looking at each fruit separately. Suppose that the $i$th customer buys $x_i$ apples, where $x_i \ge 0.$ Then, you want to count the number of solutions to the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 10.$$ This link talks about how to count the number of nonnegative integer solutions to equations of this form: https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/

Comment: oh yeah that's true, I was just posting something that the OP could get started with